# Adapt website resolution to iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, web

which is made to iframe on a 620x400 iframe, but everything I do doesn't work.. in css I already made the

```css
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 620px) {

}

/* AND */

@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
 }
```

These don't work... Anyone an idea? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide an explanation of doesn't work?

Comment: The website size in the iframe is the same size like the website in browser. So the text is like big and going out of divs..

Comment: ^^ Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the page will always be in an iframe with a predefined width, there shouldn't be a need for mediaqueries at all.

Comment: But what can help me to adapt my website to the iframe width?

Comment: If the width is always constant, you can design to that width and not worry about mediaqueries.